# Spotify Web API: Adding tracks to a playlist causes the access token to expire and returns an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, spotify, playlist

I am calling ajax call to add a single track to existing playlist. Whenever this call is made the token is immediately expired and throwing error for me. Please look into the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/users/' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '/playlists/' + encodeURIComponent(playlist) + '/tracks?position=0&uris=' + encodeURIComponent("spotify:track:" + track),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    headers:
    {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getAccessToken()
    }
}).success(function (r) {
    console.log('added track to playlist', r);
ret.resolve(r);
}).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Please help me in this so that I can fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. The token is never expired by making a call to an endpoint. It expires after a set amount of time. My guess is (without more information) that you do not have the correct scopes to be able to modify the playlist. Please provide the error message that you get back from the web api.

Comment: the scope is set as playlist-modify-public and playlist-modify-private both and also the expires as set for 3600000 and i hope it is enough for expire time. Other calls are running successfully but whenever I am making above call to endpoint the token immediately expired and I need to login again and that time I got the error 401 with message access token is expired.

Comment: Strange. Can you give me the exact playlist url you are targeting?

Comment: I am able to add through api console but not with this ajax call. The playlist is is '0w6I6qLlSxXpi3wGLoHLBb' and the track id that I want to add to this is '5g7rJvWYVrloJZwKiShqlS'. The playlist is currently private.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire playlist URI? I.e. playlist:user:<username>:playlist:<id>. I can't reproduce this issue. Could you please explain how you are retrieving and accessing the access token?

Comment: hello michael, I am using the thirtyfy sample javascript code base to authenticate and retrieve the access token. For all other endpoints it is working fine. Just adding track if to a playlist is producing this error. If you need I can show you a demo on teamviewer.

Comment: It would be useful to have access to a demo. As far as I know this should work just fine.

Comment: okay let me provide you a demo very soon.

Comment: can you please provide you email id, So that i can give you a demo project.